# Raspberry pi hardware simulation wtithout board

Tags: raspberry-pi, simulation, hardware, sensors

I hope you are well,
please, anyone, know how can I do a **hardware** simulation of **raspberry pi** with other sensors without having the board?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'other sensors' you are referring to a sense HAT then,

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-sense-hat/2

this link will give you a hardware emulation of a sense HAT that can log temp, pressure, humidity and a lot more!

Cheers,

Levi

Comment: Thanks, I want a simulator that contains sensors and raspberry pi to try some codes.